# Chrome: Notifications not working, permission not requested

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I have been struggling for hours on trying to enable notifications on `chrome`, on firefox it works perfectly and it works ok as well on `localhost` url address. But when it comes to non-localhost url address it just doesn't work.

i have been checking on the permissions that are displayed left next to the url input box where you see the website's information and it shows that notifications are permitted, but on advanced settings it shows `block` with a message "Blocked to protect your privacy" and i am not entirely sure what does that mean.

the code i am trying to execute first is simple:

```
if(Notifications.permission == "default"){
    Notification.requestPermission()
        .then(permission => {
            console.log(`Permission given is: ${permission}`);
        });

}

else{
    console.log("Notification permission is: ${Notification.permission}`);
}
```

The result of this code is `Notification permission is: denied` meaning that `else` statement was executed but permission is given as if permission was already requested and denied was the answer of the request.

Can someone explain why does this happen?

Comment: `Notifications.permission` obviously doesn't equal to `"default"`, that's why the code goes to the `else` block.

Comment: @Teemu i know it is not equal to `default`, but i don't know why it goes to `denied` when no permission was even requested on the first place

Comment: ?? Because at the time you check the value of `Notifications.permission` in the condition, its value is `"denied"`.

Comment: @Teemu i am asking why it is `denied`, on first visit it is automatically set on `denied`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was comming from loading the website with no TLS `https`, making some features in chrome to be disabled by design..

I was unabled to figure this out sooner because the host testing i was using was being accessed with `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` which is the one that chrome whitelists for features